# How to validate a Rummikub combination with Jokers

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

In the game of Rummikub, for those who don't know it, you have tiles in 4 colours and with 13 different numbers on them (so 4 x 13 = 52 unique tiles) which you must use to make groups. There are two kinds of groups:

- Different colours, same numbers (e.g. `R1-B1-G1`)
- Same colours, sequence of numbers (e.g. `G6-G7-G8`)

I'm writing code that takes a list of tiles and checks if it's a valid combination. So far it works and is pretty straightforward.

It gets difficult when we introduce Joker tiles. You can use these as any tile to complete a combination (e.g. `G6-R6-J`) and you can use multiple (e.g. `R4-R5-J-J-R8`).

I figured that I'd validate combinations with Jokers in two steps:

1. Replace all Jokers with the tile they are standing in for.
2. Validate the "normalized" group with the existing code (unless step 1 threw an error because it already saw the combination is invalid).

Now, how to do step 1? I think it's fairly simple if only one Joker is allowed per group:

- If the tiles adjacent to the joker are of the same colour and the right one is 2 higher than the left one, replace with the number inbetween
- If the adjacent tiles have the same number but different colours, replace with a colour that is not yet present.
- And the same but modified a bit if the Joker is at the beginning or end

Unfortunately, multiple Jokers are allowed, which makes this a bit more complex, and I'm stuck on how to solve that.

Comment: Actually, I think the best method to do what you're asking for is when you check if the sequence is valid, you should count the valid cards. If it's a joker, add to count automatically rather than checking it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insist to perform step 1 as the first thing you do, you're making trouble for yourself. It's simply computationally inefficient to approach the problem from that angle. What you would end up doing with that approach, is to try all combinations of stand-ins for the jokers.
That is a bad idea.

Here's an alternative approach that will work with little effort:

1. Does the group contain 0 or 1 non-joker, and does the group contain at least three pieces then success.
2. Are all colors of the non-jokers have the same color, then success.
3. Does all the pieces lay like (1, 2, joker, 4) where all jokers automatically take the value one higher than the preceding piece. If so, then success.
4. If none of the above were true, then fail.

Perform all those checks in turn, and you will find if a group of pieces is a valid group.

For step 3 in this, you have to consider that some sequences could be in reverse, say (joker, 3, 2, 1).
to detect such cases, you can do a quick scan over the non-jokers, to see if they increment or they decrement, and then take that into account (the jokers will then have the value one less than the previous).

Notice that only in step 2 are the colors significant, and only in step 3 are the numbers significant.

Comment: Almost correct. Step 2 should be *do they have the same value* and step 3 should check if they all have the same colour

Comment: I don't remember the exact rules of the game. Ofcourse if three of the same value is a valid group, then they should also be checked under step two (addition to step two).

Answer (score 5):

Recently, I wrote an Android Rummikub game and may be, my code helps you
(or may be too late; but still could help someone else).
I am not sure, if there are bugs in it. Because I have not checked it much.

I assume number 0~105.
Corresponding cards are Black Red Yellow Green and GhostCard
(B1 ~ 0, B13 ~ 12, R1 ~ 13 ... G13 ~ 51, B1 ~52 ... G13 ~103 GHOST1~104,GHOST2~105)

Here is the code:

```
public boolean isLegal(List<Byte> cards)
{
    byte ghostNum = 0; 
    byte ghostRemain = 0;
    byte size = (byte) cards.size();
    if (size == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (size < 3)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //get the num of ghostcard
    Collections.sort(cards);
    if (cards.get(size - 1) >= 104)
    {
        ghostNum++;
        if (cards.get(size - 2) >= 104)
        {
            ghostNum++;
        }
    }
    ghostRemain = ghostNum;

    byte[] a = new byte[size - ghostNum];
    byte[] b = new byte[size - ghostNum];
    for (byte i = 0; i < size - ghostNum; i++)
    {
        a[i] = (byte) (cards.get(i) % 13); // the num of the tiles 0~12
        b[i] = (byte) ((cards.get(i) / 13) % 4); // the color of the tiles 0~3(B,R,Y,G)
    }
    Arrays.sort(a);
    Arrays.sort(b);
    // tiles seems in same color
    if (b[0] == b[size - 1 - ghostNum])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1 - ghostNum; i++)
        {
            if (a[i + 1] - a[i] != 1)
            {
                ghostRemain = (byte) (ghostRemain - a[i + 1] + a[i] + 1);
                if (ghostRemain < 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (b[i] != b[i + 1])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
        // tiles in different colors
    }
    else if (b[0] != b[1])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1 - ghostNum; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] != a[i + 1])
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (b[i] == b[i + 1])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've built a Rummikub solver based on work by D. Den Hertog, P. B. Hulshof, described in their paper "Solving Rummikub Problems by Integer Linear Programming" (*The Computer Journal, 49(6), 2006*, pages 665-669, [DOI 10.1093/comjnl/bxl033](https://doi.org/10.1093/comjnl/bxl033)). This uses [Mixed-Integer Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) to find possible solutions given the tiles on the player's rack and the tiles in play on the board. If you leave the rack empty, the same algorithm will tell you if what is placed on the table can be grouped into valid sets.

Not that you need to have such a sophisticated algorithm for this subset of the game, of course. If all you want to know if *existing* sets on the table are correct, I would just generate all *possible* sets of such tiles. There are only 1174 such sets (although 431 of those are sets where you can just take out one or two of the jokers without invalidating the set). Put those into a hash table for O(N) membership testing and all you need to do is test each set on the table against this table.

You can generate all those possible sets up front. You can place *runs* and *groups*. Runs are tiles of the same colour placed in incremental order, so the number values "9, 10, 11, 12" for a single colour, and groups are tiles with the same number value, but different colours, e.g. 3 or 4 "9" tiles. Sets are always between 3 and 5 tiles long, because any *longer* sets can be broken up into still-valid sets of just 3, 4 or 5 tiles each (groups are always 3 or 4 tiles long).

Generating all possible groups and runs without jokers is pretty trivial, I won't go into those here. But to add jokers, you only need to produce all valid [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of a valid set without jokers, and one or two of the tiles replaced by jokers.

In Python, generating combinations is pretty easy, the standard library [includes a `combinations()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). If `sets` is an iterable of valid groups or runs, you can add jokers with:

```py
from itertools import chain, combinations

jokers = ["joker", "joker"]
with_jokers = chain.from_iterable(
    combinations([*set, *jokers], len(set)) for set in sets
)
```

Don't worry if you don't know what [`chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) does; it just flattens out the output of `combinations()` into a single series of sets.

For a simplified series of *group* sets `[('black 1', 'blue 1', 'orange 1'), ('black 1', 'blue 1', 'red 1'), ('black 1', 'orange 1', 'red 1'), ('blue 1', 'orange 1', 'red 1'), ('black 1', 'blue 1', 'orange 1', 'red 1')]` (all possible groups with the number 1), the above would generate the following unique combinations:

- black 1, blue 1, joker
- black 1, blue 1, joker, joker
- black 1, blue 1, orange 1
- black 1, blue 1, orange 1, joker
- black 1, blue 1, orange 1, red 1
- black 1, blue 1, red 1
- black 1, blue 1, red 1, joker
- black 1, joker, joker
- black 1, orange 1, joker
- black 1, orange 1, joker, joker
- black 1, orange 1, red 1
- black 1, orange 1, red 1, joker
- black 1, red 1, joker
- black 1, red 1, joker, joker
- blue 1, joker, joker
- blue 1, orange 1, joker
- blue 1, orange 1, joker, joker
- blue 1, orange 1, red 1
- blue 1, orange 1, red 1, joker
- blue 1, red 1, joker
- blue 1, red 1, joker, joker
- orange 1, joker, joker
- orange 1, red 1, joker
- orange 1, red 1, joker, joker
- red 1, joker, joker

That's 25 different combinations, all valid sets (although you wouldn't want to play the 4-set long groups with a joker in a real game). The code above also generates 30 duplicates, you need to eliminate those from the output; I use a Python `set` object for that. For group sets, it works exactly the same way.

These are sets in *sorted order*, make sure to sort the sets on the table to test against these. Put all these valid sets into hash table or similar structure (e.g. a Python set), and for a layout on the table to be legal, all sets on the table must be one of these generated sets.

---

The code for the solver is [on Github](https://github.com/mjpieters/RummikubConsole/), the [`RuleSet` class](https://github.com/mjpieters/RummikubConsole/blob/master/src/rummikubconsole/ruleset.py) is responsible for generating these sets. It differs from the above in that it uses integers to represent each tile, and the Rummikub rules are configurable. Because it is acting as a solver, it doesn't generate sets with redundant jokers.